# MySQL processes gets killed after 900 seconds

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I hope this is the right place to ask..

I am facing a strange issue where the connection to the mariadb server gets terminated after a certain time. Like I am trying to connect to the mariadb server through HeidiSQL app, and after 900 seconds of idle state, the connection gets closed. I have been monitoring this by logging into the mariadb server via command line. Under show processlist, the process id remains in sleep mode state for 900 seconds, and it terminates without any reason. The wait_timeout and max_allowed_packets are 8 hours and 1 GB respectively. With wait_timeout at 8 hours, mysql shouldn't be killing the process after 900 seconds (if it is mariadb that is causing this issue)

I been looking into this all day and I'm kinda out of ideas. Can anyone help me with this?

Mariadb10.1.13

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in the end the issue was related to the hardware firewall as there was an inactivity timeout set at 900 seconds. Kinda embarrassing if I think why I haven't thought about it earlier, but yea thats the reason for this issue. Just thought I should update it here instead of deleting the question so that others can refer.